# Forward rolling 365 day groupby sum - irregular intervals

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of transactional data that looks like the below:

| Customer_ID | Day | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-08-01 | 80.11 |
| 2 | 2019-01-07 | 10.15 |
| 2 | 2021-02-21 | 74.15 |
| 1 | 2019-06-18 | 10.00 |
| 3 | 2020-03-17 | 15.15 |
| 2 | 2020-04-29 | 80.98 |
| 4 | 2016-06-01 | 133.54 |
| 3 | 2022-01-14 | 17.15 |
| 2 | 2021-02-28 | 25.12 |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | 1.22 |

I need to calculate the forward rolling 365 day sum of sales grouped by the customer, exclusive of the current day. I would like to insert the result as a new column.

e.g. for customer_id == 1 for the first row, the value to be inserted in the new column will be the sum of sales between 2018-08-02 and 2019-08-01 for customer_id == 1.

I'm sure there's a way to do this using pandas, but I can't figure it out.

Code to produce the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Customer_ID': [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1],
'Day': ['2018-01-01', '2019-01-07', '2021-02-21', '2019-06-17', '2020-03-17', '2020-04-29', '2016-06-01', '2022-01-14', '2021-02-28', '2021-01-02'],
'Sales': [80.11, 10.15, 74.15, 10.00, 15.15, 80.98, 133.54, 17.15, 25.12, 1.22]
})

df.Day = pd.to_datetime(df.Day)
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example instead of a table picture?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this sorry, the data in the above table is more than enough to display the problem.

Comment: Something like: `Customer_ID = ["1","2","2","1","3","2","4"]`

Comment: @JAdel I've edited the post to include code to produce the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to `groupby` the Customer_ID column, then perform a rolling sum on each group after you set the 'Day' column as each groups index.

```
df.groupby('Customer_ID')
    .apply(
        lambda gr: gr.set_index('Day').sort_index()['Sales'].rolling('365D').sum()
    ).reset_index()
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but for me this is the simplest one for me.

Comment: Pretty sure this just finds the backward rolling sum, but I need the forward sum, i.e. the sum of the next 365 days, not the previous.

Comment: Forgot about that part. That one will be pretty hairy since for that you will need to calculate the rolling sum of the reverse group. If the rolling window is defined by an offset this will fail because the index is not monotonically increasing. Check out this link https://tousu.in/qa/?qa=4271669/ and try to implement the described method in a function that will be applied to each group.